# IntelliJ Idea, run code regardless of errors in unrelated project files

Tags: compiler-errors, intellij-idea

One thing that I miss from Eclipse is that I can't run code for testing various things (think short main()) if some totally unrelated files in my project contain errors. I've read in FAQ that I can use Eclipse compiler with -proceedOnErrors argument but it still doesn't work. Temporarily fixing unfinished code to compile is not really what I want.

I should note that I use Scala plugin too but still majority of my code are Java files.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Modify your configuration to use `Make, no error check` option instead of `Make`.

For more information [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16784855/607767)

Note that this may not be enough in your use case. Last resort is to use the solution provided by [Vics answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10858442/607767).

Comment: Great, destroy all error handling. What about compile and execute this *** main method in isolation

Comment: @momo Compiler still generates errors, it's just the `make`r that ignores them afterwards. Also, as explained in 'see this answer' above, change compiler to eclipse because javac indeed stops at the first error whereas eclipse gladly continues.

Answer (score 43):

Well, you can do it. The important part, of course, that the class with the `main` function compiles.

There are two ways you can go:

1. Compile the class that you want to run only (CTRL Shift F9). Run the `main` function with a right click. It will fail, but IntelliJ will automagically create a temporary running configuration for this `main` function. Now edit this configuration and uncheck the option to "Make before launch". Then go back to the file and launch the `main` as before.
2. Go to the configurations screen, then Defaults and then Application pane. Uncheck the "Make before launch" option and then you're good to go, as in section one, for any `main` function you'll encounter/create in this project.

**Edit**

This answer is outdated, and @ipandzic's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20677403/579828) should be used

Comment: It's still not as easy as in Eclipse (I have to compile and run separately) but at least I don't have to fix whole project. Thank you.

Comment: This was quite a process.

Comment: What about compile and execute this main method in isolation. That would be an idea. Now I have to open a new project just to execute a java file without having to go through ten menus first.

Comment: This will probably disable compiling, right? How to compile, but run even if errors?

Comment: Looks like Idea is (again) not as intelligent as advertised :-D

Comment: There's no option of "make before launch" in intellij 2018. :(

Comment: @Heisenberg you're right... Looks like lpandzic's answer is the only way to go now

Comment: Even in IntelliJ 2018 there is the option "make before launch". Run/Debug Configurations -> Your Application -> Configuration -> Before launch: Build, Activate tool window -> remove the "Build" line  with the Minus symbol. That works! :) Thank You Vic!

Comment: Removing the build before launch is no option I think, but there is also a "Build, no error checks" that looks promising.
Run/Debug Configurations -> Your Application -> Configuration -> Before launch: Build, Activate tool window -> replace the "Build" line with "Build, no error checks".

Answer (score 9):

As this answer suggests (https://stackoverflow.com/a/14793361/986160) you can use Settings > Build,Execution,Deployment > Compilers > Excludes and add the parts of the projects that are unrelated to be excluded from compilation. Make sure that the part you are trying to run doesn't have imports from those excludes.

Comment: I don't know why it was downvoted, this is exactly the solution to my problem.  I have a new package that does not compile yet.  This lets me run the program.

Answer (score 8):

1. Edit the configuration.

[image]

2. With latest versions of IntelliJ, we need to remove the build from 'make
   before launch' option by clicking '-'. Below is the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Just remember to Recompile manually the classes you make changes before to launch. Build->Recompile (Ctrl+Shift+F9)

Comment: This works for me. But I think instead of remove "Build" just select "Build no error check". (Intellij IDEA 2019.1.2)

Answer (score 1):

For whatever reason, none of the above solutions worked for me, on my large legacy Gradle project. However, the error that I had was just because some method in IntelliJ wasn't wired up correctly (i.e. no obvious compilation errors with other areas of the code). As such, I ended up running `gradle clean build idea` which worked for my purposes. After that, my test class ran without issue.