# Compile on run in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

When I run a test in IntelliJ, it doesn't automatically compile the file first. Is this normal behavior? I know I can use eclipse mode to auto compile when I save, but it seems logical to auto compile before running the file. Is this possible in IntelliJ?

Comment: You should look into "Before Launch" option- [more info here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10858442/579828). Note: If its checked, the whole module/project will be rebuilt, and not only the current test file.

Comment: Thanks. I looked into this and I edited the defaults, but when I create a new run configuration by right clicking on a test file and clicking run, that doesn't have "make" checked. Is that normal?

Comment: Did you check "make" in a relevant configuration under "Defaults" section (JUnit I believe)?

Comment: I did. It seems that when generating the run configuration from within the file this still doesn't cause the "make" checkbox to be checked. If I go into the run configurations menu and create a new grails configuration, the box is checked.

Comment: So the defaults for Grails is checked, but when you have Intellij to autocreate new Grails configuration, the make is unchecked? Perhaps you should [submit a bug request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com)

Comment: I will do that, thanks. If you convert your comments into an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Issue opened as http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-94374 (note this only seems to happen with integration tests)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made a macro to Save and Compile mapped to `CMD+s`

Also made a macro to Save, Compile, and Run mapped to `CMD+r`

EDIT:

According to this link: http://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2012/12/28/a-new-way-to-compile/

**Using the SBT incrementality type rather than IDEA will better detect modifications to the scala files and function as we expect.**

Preferences -> Build -> Compiler -> Scala

Comment: I did the same thing just yesterday

Comment: @JeffStorey Its pretty damn annoying now. Got to file an issue with jetbrains.

Answer (score 8):

There is a "Before Launch" option group under configuration screen, that has "Make" as one of the options. If this option is checked, the whole module/project will be rebuilt prior launching.

If you want this option to persist for all future configurations automatically created by IntelliJ, mark it under relevant configuration in "Defaults" group.

Comment: best answer for java users.

Comment: I'm not finding the "Before Launch" option group in IntelliJ 2019.3. Is there a different way to achieve this with the newer version.

Comment: @izhang, it's still there in the Run/Debug Configurations, at least for "Application" and "Junit" types.

Comment: @Vic Thanks, I've found it now. I was looking in preferences rather than configurations before.