# How to make IntellijIDEA ignore work-in-progress class files?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When I'm working in IntellijIDEA how do I tell it to ignore a class file that may have problems and I want to leave dormant for a while?

It will throw errors when I compile whatever class I am working on until I fix the first "dormant" class.

I have tried adding my class to a bogus package but Intellij doesn't like that either because the path doesn't match.

[image: IntellijIDEA]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`Settings` | `Compiler` | `Excludes`, add your WIP files there:

[image: exclude]

Comment: Thank-you CrazyCoder.  To anyone reading this... I tried to make my use case as simple as possible but I find that the answer doesn't apply to my real scenario.  Do I add another screenshot and edit my original question or start a new question?

Comment: I believe that this answer covers the original question. If you have another question/scenario, make it a new one to avoid confusion and requiring all the users who already responded to edit their answers.

Answer (score 4):

You could use **Refactor** -> **Rename File...**, and change the file extension.

Answer (score 3):

That is set at the inspection level

Configure Current File Analysis <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>

I have profiles with differing inspection levels setup loosely based on the phase of my project builds ... I'd suggest taking a look at [Customizing Inspection Profiles](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/customizing-profiles.html).

[image]

To ignore specific files during compilation you can add files individually or recursively in via the project settings panel ...

[Configure Compiler Analysis](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/compiler-validation.html) <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> :: Compiler => Validation

[image]

Comment: This affects highlighting and inspections, but how does it skip a file during compilation?

Comment: @weltraumpirat That would be set via [Compiler Validation](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/compiler-validation.html)

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, still

If all your files are in the same package, then right-click on the package in the Project tool window and pick "Mark directory as -> Excluded". 
All the classes inside the package won't be compiled. You can cancel exclusion any time you want the same way.

Comment: I've found that this only sometimes works, and I have to use Compiler -> Excludes in the settings to make it ignore files reliably.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, only the classes that are used in the application are actually compiled.
In your case, I would guess that it's only broken unit tests that hinder the compilation (as opposed to any other Java classes in the `/main` folder).

The reason is this: When running all unit tests in a package or source folder, IntelliJ searches and includes all the files that *appear* like unit tests by default: those with `Test` or `Suite` in the class name, but also those annotated with `@Test` or `@Suite`.

So the easiest way to exclude your test is to create a third source folder, call it /ignore, and *not* mark it as a source folder in IntelliJ.  You can then drop any file you don't want to include in your compilation there temporarily, and drag it back to its original folder when you want to continue working on it.  Beware, though: You will get only limited tool support if you open and edit the file within an unmarked source folder, so it should really be used for "parking" only.

You could also change the file extension, as the other answer suggests, but then IntelliJ will also change its handling of the file in other respects, not just during compilation.

Also, if you're using JUnit 4, you can always annotate any single test method, or the entire test class, with `@Ignore`, and it will be skipped during the test run.  This requires the class to be formally correct, though, i.e.: no compile time errors.

P.S: You need to actually move the test to a different folder, if you really want the package to change - not just edit the `package` declaration. Otherwise, a non-matching declaration will also be considered an error.