# How to run specific java file without entire project build (Gradle) to happen in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ IDEA, (Gradle based Java project) how to run a specific Java class with main method without Gradle build operation?

[image]

Comment: You may annotate the method you want to execute with @Test and then run as a "JUnit test" via the right mouse button. See https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JUnit/article.html for a tutorial.

Comment: Are you not able to run by right clicking and run as java program ?

Comment: Hi Sambit, when i do right-click -> Run, the Gradle build is triggered. Updated my question with screenshot on this

Comment: Check this link. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-java-application.html

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/16784855/104891. Disable build delegation: https://i.imgur.com/HpeUaUE.png.