# How to run a main method method without building the WHOLE maven project in idea?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, main-method

I have a maven project with many demo classes with their own main methods, they don't dependent on each other. I used to be able to run a class by right clicking on its main method, and select `Run MyClass.main()`. But now instead of running it, it started to build the maven project as a whole.

[image]

Is there a way to "fix" this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/16784855/2000323

Answer (score 2):

IDE performs tasks that are set in **Before launch** section of the Run/Debug Configuration. By default the **Build** set is set there - which will build the all the sources which deletd on the code you are trying to run.

1. You can remove the **Build** step from there and build the module alone from the module context menu of this module. See [compile module](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/compiling-applications.html#compile_module) for more description.
2. Use **Build, no error check** step in **Before launch** section.

Comment: Could you share a gif screenshot or a video? My Idea's version is 2020.3 and the UI might have changed.

Answer (score 1):

Check that in the settings the *"Delegate IDE build..."* is not selected:

[image: project settings]

Comment: This step is necessary, but I still cannot run a single class without the IDE checking other classes

Comment: Author, Were you able to achieve this?