# How to enable partial build in intellij (Gradle)?

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

Despite reading this [popular post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16784703/enable-partial-compilation-in-intellij-idea), I couldn't find the solution to building only a subset of a Java project.

So far I've tried:

- Creating a new run/debug configuration with `Build, no error check` and removing `Build`.
- Under `Build, Execution, Deployment` > `Compiler`, I have unchecked `Automatically show first error in editor`.
- Inside `Build, Execution, Deployment` > `Compiler` > `Java Compiler`, I have selected `Eclipse` and checked `Proceed on errors`.

**EDIT**

I am using the latest version of Intellij with Gradle and JDK 1.8. I wrote some gibberish inside BrokenOnPurpose.java and the objective was to get the compiler to ignore the file. But instead, I get a "Task compileJava failed" with an error, stopped dead in its tracks.

```
src
├── main
│   ├── java
│   │   ├── BrokenOnPurpose.java
│   │   └── Main.java (*)
│   └── resources
└...
(*) entry method
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work for you? Does it stop on the first error without compiling any other files? Please provide the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yes, that's what it did. I've added more information in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [disable gradle build delegation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ih7Sk.png) for your compiler settings to have effect.