# How to run project with errors in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, compiler-errors

It is possible to run a project, which contains errors in `Eclipse`.

I think it is normal for project with many files to contain some erroneous files to fix in the future and still be able to run it.

Unfortunately, I can't find this possibility in `IntelliJ`.

Methods proposed in this answer [IntelliJ Idea, run code regardless of errors in unrelated project files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851880/intellij-idea-run-code-regardless-of-errors-in-unrealted-project-files) do not work for me.

It throws `ClassNotFoundException` in the class with main. Class itself contains no errors and was running under Eclipse. There is no apparent appropriate `*.class` file in `target/classes` directory.

Comment: Did you consider commenting them out, or just removing them from the project temporarily. Besides, I really don't see this as being a limitation. If your code is broken - fix it! Then run afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

In your run configuration, you can tell it not to make before running.

You can compile individual files through their right-click menu or (from memory) Ctrl+Shift+F9 if the file you want to compile is in the editor.

A combination of these two will mostly achieve what you want, although this is probably the key paradigm difference between IntelliJ and Eclipse, and you'd be using IntelliJ in a sort of non-IntellliJ way (if you see what I mean).