# How to run Java scratch file in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

I just start using `IntelliJ-14` and I want to know about a scratch file. If I create a java scratch can I compile this as a normal `Java` class.
What I Have Already Tried
Create a `Java` class in a scratch file but unable to find any way to compile this.
What I am looking for rather than creating a new `Java` file in an existing project for running some test code I just want to use scratch file and write some test class with the main method and after complete running close the scratch file. Is that possible?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Executability for Java scratch files was [added in IntelliJ 15](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-140228), so you must upgrade for that feature.

You have several option how to run/debug the scratch file:

- Click the icon next to the main method/class
- Hit <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> on Linux/Windows) somewhere within the scratch file
- Right click inside the method/class and select appropriate run/debug option

---

[image]

Comment: I get an error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35457087/error-running-scratch-file-in-intellij-15

Comment: Anyone knows how to build and run just the scratch file, without building the whole project?

Comment: @IvanBalashov check here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851880/intellij-idea-run-code-regardless-of-errors-in-unrelated-project-files