# IntelliJ - How to run current program regardless of errors in unrelative files

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea

I am start learning Scala, I am using

> Java 7 and
>
> IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.4
>
> Build #IC-145.2070, built on August 2, 2016
>
> JRE: 1.8.0_77-b03 x86 JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM by Oracle Corporation

I got some sample code programs online and trying to run one by one.

But not working, while I try to run, it showing errors in other files but there is no relationship with them, all most all are independent Scala classes only.

[IntelliJ Idea, run code regardless of errors in unrelated project files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851880/intellij-idea-run-code-regardless-of-errors-in-unrealted-project-files)

I followed this similar issue, but I am not able to find options they suggested. like "Make before launch" and other might be very old post.

Comment: Show the errors. Provide [mcve]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The option is still there, you just need to look for it in your *run configuration window*.

As you can see in the below GIF, when you create a run configuration it will implicitly run `make` before running, and initially it will fail.

The, you edit the *run configuration* and replace `make` with `make, no error check`. If you get a `ClassNotFoundException` when launching it right after, just re-run it again. I haven't figured out why this happens, it's probably related to how IJ cleans and compiles the classes in this particular case.

[image: make, no error check]

Comment: @Ravi no problem, glad I could help

Comment: is there any way to do for project setting or in IntelliJ settings to run program regardless of compilation issues in other irrelative files. Because, I have to do this for every program before run.

Comment: @Ravi Yes, in the same window you have to change the _default_ configuration from which all future such configs will inherit their initial settings. Just expand the _Defaults_ item from the tree on the left, select _Application_ (or whatever type of run configuration you have) and do the same as in the GIF.